# lp failing to print

Tags: printing, pdf, 21.10, brother, cups-lpd

I've reinstalled my laptop by deleting my previous Ubuntu 20.04 install and fresh installed Ubuntu 21.10 (updated to latest available updates).

Now that I'm trying to print a lot of PDF files with a simple `lp *` as I was doing before, only one document is printed and nothing else happens. When I try to print a single document with lp nothing comes out of the printer.

The Wi-Fi printer (Brother_HL_L2350DW_series) has been selected as the default (and only) printer. When printing from the GUI it takes a bit to launch but it prints all the documents fine one by one.

I don't remember having had to do anything to install the printer. If I do a search for drivers it says "No suitable driver found".

How can I figure out what's not working and fix it? It is a great time saver for me when I have to print a lot of one page documents.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you set your printer as the default printer? (`lpoptions`? `lpadmin`?) Please show the output of `lpstat` and `lpstat -s`.

Comment: I chose it in the Printers GUI dialog. lpstat returns nothing, with -s I get: "system default destination: Brother_HL_L2350DW_series
device for Brother_HL_L2350DW_series: implicitclass://Brother_HL_L2350DW_series/
"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question. Copy&paste commands and output and format it as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. What happens when you use `lp` to print a file? Does it print a request ID? Does it create a print job that gets processed (somehow)? Can you print an ASCII file or a PostScript file? You could use `ps2pdf` or `pstopdf` to convert a PDF file to a PostScript file. Please also copy&paste the output of `lpstat -W completed`. Look for messages related to `lp` or `cups` in `/var/log`.

Comment: Just a comment, this behaviour has been irritating me on Fedora since I thing F35. So this is not necessarily Ubuntu specific, you just get it a little later.

Answer (score 0):

What worked to fix it:

1. Remove the printer.
2. Add the printer.
3. Select it as default.